# Why EF Entities are making a dependency and the need of POCO

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, poco

I'm pretty new to IoC, Dependency Injection and Unit Testing. I'm starting a new pet project and I'm trying to do it right.

I was planning to use the Repository pattern to mediate with the data. The objects that I was going to return from the repositories were going to be objects collected from a **Linq to entities data context** (EF4).

I'm reading in "Dependency Injection" from Mark Seeman that doing it, makes an important dependency and will definitely complicate the testing (that's what he's using POCO objects in a Library Project).

I'm not understanding why. Although the objects are created by a linq to entities context, I can create them simply calling the constructor as they were normal objects. So I assume that is possible to create fake repositories that deviler these objects to the caller.

I'm also concerned about the automatic generation of POCO classes, which is not very easy.

Can somebody bring some light? Are POCO objects trully necessary for a decoupled and testable project?

****EDIT: Thanks to Yuck I understand that it's better to avoid autogeneration with templates, which brings me to a design question. If I come from a big legacy database wich his tables are assuming a variety of responsabilities (doesn't fit well with the concept of a class with a single responsability), what's the best way to deal with that?**

**Delete the database is not an option ;-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not necessary it just makes things easier, cleaner.

The POCO library won't have any knowledge that it's being used by Entity Framework. This allows it to be used in other ways - in place of a view model, for instance. It also allows you to use the same project on both sides of a WCF service which eliminates the need to create data transfer objects (DTO).

Just two examples from personal experience but there are surely more. In general the **less** a particular object or piece of code knows about who is using it or how it's being used will make it **more** adaptable and generic for other situations.

You also mention *automatic generation of POCO classes*. I don't recommend doing this. Were you planning to generate the class definitions from your database structure?

Comment: Thanks Yuck for your time. It' very valuable for me. I would like to clarify about the generation of POCO classes. Although it's a pet project, I'm coming from a database structure (and I'm interested in learning the best way to do it). The automatic generation of classes saves time and in legacy projects can help to represent easily big assets of data. Anyway, I understand that it's better to avoid autogeneration with templates. What's the best way to act when you have to import pretty big tables?

Comment: @user1171844 I mean, you can certainly *start* by generating them from your db structure. But part of the benefit EF provides is allowing you to define classes that don't match the db schema 1:1. So you can split tables, combine related entities and so on. Just keep that in mind while you're working through the POCO project.

Answer (score 2):

> I was planning to use the Repository pattern to mediate with the data.
>   The objects that I was going to return from the repositories were
>   going to be objects collected from a Linq to entities data context
>   (EF4).

The default classes (not the POCOs) EF generates contain proxies for lazy loading and are tied at the hip to Entity Framework. That means any other class that wants to use those classes will have to reference the required EF assemblies.

This is the dependency Mark Seeman is talking about. Since you are now dependent on these non-abstract types, which in turn are dependent on EF, you cannot simply change the implementation of your repository to something different (i.e. just using your own persistence store) without addressing this change in the class that depend on these types.

If you are truly only interested in the public properties of the EF generated types then you can have the partial classes generated by EF implement a base interface. Put all the properties you need in that base interface and pass the dependency in as the base interface - now you only depend on the base interface and not EF anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot ;). Lazy loading it's an important detail I was missing.